# Laravel backpack select2_from_ajax setting my value as null after the correct value has been saved

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Im having a weird problem.
Im using laravel backpack for an admin panel. There i use select2_from_ajax to list a values according to another field in create operation. It is showing up correctly as expected & i can select one too.
But after selection when i click save & back it gives me an error[image: integraty constraint failure]

That means my column doesn't allow to update to null right.
So when i go back & check the column it has saved the correct value.
But when default value of my column was null this error will not showup & db value would be changed to null.

This is my select2_from_ajax part.

```
    $this->crud->addField([  // Select
        'label' => "Link Type",
        'type' => 'select_from_array',
        'name' => 'link_type', // the db column for the foreign key
        'options'     => [1 => 'Product',0 => 'Collection'],
        'allows_null' => false,
    ]);

    $this->crud->addField([  // Select
        'label' => "Link To", // Table column heading
        'type' => "select2_from_ajax",
        'name' => "link_to",
        'entity' => 'link',
        'attribute'   => "name",
        'data_source' => url('admin/itemtype'),
        'placeholder' => "Select a item",
        'minimum_input_length' => 0,
        'include_all_form_fields' => true,
        'dependencies' => ['link_type'],
    ]);
```

So why is it trying to set null value after the correct value?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

My admin/itemtype function:

```
    $search_term = $request->input('q');
    $form = collect($request->input('form'))->pluck('value', 'name');

    if ($search_term) {
        if ($form['link_type'] == 0) {
            $items = Collection::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_term . '%')->paginate(10);
        } else {
            $items = Product::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_term . '%')->paginate(10);
        }
    } else {
        if ($form['link_type'] == 0) {
            $items = Collection::paginate(10);
        } else {
            $items = Product::paginate(10);
        }
    }


    return $items;
```

Comment: please share the action that respond to this route: admin/itemtype

Comment: @OMR updated the question. Thanks.